# Possible to statically link shared object libraries?

Tags: shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, static-linking

I'm building a library that needs to be dynamically linked to my project. The output is a .so file, so I think I'm on the right track. I'm concerned by the way it's being linked at compile time - by specifying the location of its makefile and depending on a bunch of macros, which I've never encountered before.

Can I assume that since I'm building a .so library (rather than a .a) that I'm in fact dynamically linking? Or is it possible for .so libs to be statically linked, in which case I need to rip apart the make/config files to better understand what's going on?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with internal structure of executables and shared objects, so I could only give some practical hints.

Assuming you use `gcc`, it should have `-shared` option when linking object files into library - this way `ld` (called by `gcc`) makes shared object instead of executable binary.

```
gcc -shared -o libabc.so *.o ...
```

When you link some application with this libabc.so it should link without errors and after that with `ldd` command you should be able to see `libabc.so` among its dependencies.

```
$ ldd app
    ...
    libabc.so => ...............
```